# SQL Server running slow due to thread count increase

Tags: sql, sql-server

On our production server, for some reason at specific amount of time, thread count goes over and over to the certain point that though CPU Utilization is normal(30-50%), but the query starting to run slow we so lot more blocking statements.

I am not sure where to look at it, basically when our site runs normally, the thread count is around 150 threads, but during the specific time in a day(during 1:30 to 2:30) it come up to 270 threads.there are no extra sql transaction goes on, everything as normal as it was before but thread count grows and sql start behaving very very slow.

After restarting the SQL service immediately thread count comes to normal, and our site function fine for another 24 hours.

We are using SQL Server 2005, it is 24 core machine.

any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Blocking statements steal workers ([`sys.dm_os_workers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms178626%28v=sql.90%29)) so the server will spawn more workers to handle the incoming tasks. At 24 cores you'll have some 700 [`max worker threads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187024%28v=sql.105%29) out-of-the-box by default. So seeing 270 'threads' is not an issue, is well within the normal functioning parameters. You real problem must be the blocking, and you have to investigate it accordingly: who is blocking who and why. My bet is that you have a job running between 1:30 and 2:30 that is locking large portions of the database (a delete job perhaps?) and your queries block on locked rows. You'll have to investigate, find the root cause, and act accordingly. Reboot is not a solution, nor is blaming unrelated components (thread count). Use [Activity Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc879320%28v=sql.105%29), use [Who Is Active](https://web.archive.org/web/20170921095748/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2010/10/21/who-is-active-v10-00-dmv-monitoring-made-easy.aspx), follow the methodical approach of [Waits and Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/cc966413%28v=technet.10%29) methodology. There are plenty of ways to identify the *real* problem. SQL Server will *never* appear slow due to thread count. It simply [doesn't work like that](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312113831/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/02/05/367816.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can control the degree of parallalism using the MAXDOP query hint. For more details please check this article:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/15/sql-server-maxdop-settings-to-limit-query-to-run-on-specific-cpu/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable feedback, yes it is true it is nothing which sql is behaving weiredly, it is something our Site which is based on Ektron CMS is responsible for, one of the Functionality of Ektron CMS (which is PageBuilder), while doing operation on this piece of Content was holding of the table badly, we have around 10 million users to our site, and probably since this was blocking the tables SQL Server goes nuts and does not respond very well.

We have finally eliminated the issue.